# Complex data transformation optimization in R

Tags: r, loops, vectorization

I've written some really, really ugly code to perform a data transformation. I know that it can probably be vectorized and sped up significantly, but I'm not sure how.

The data I have looks like this:

```
scores<-as.data.frame(cbind(c(1,2,3,3,1,2,3,1,2,1,2,3),c(5,5,5,5,6,6,6,7,7,8,8,8),
c(0,1,1,1,1,0,1,.5,"fickle",1,2.2,1),c(1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)))
names(dat)<-c("name","question_id","correct","attempt")
ids<-c(5,7,8)
```

What I want is to create a studentXquestion matrix that shows their final attempt score on every question that is included in the ids vector. It would also give NA if the student did not complete that question, or 99 if some value other than 0 or 1 appears in the "correct" column, as some data is a little ugly.

Below is the code I have so far.

```
students<-unique(scores$name)
finaldat<-data.frame(matrix(ncol=length(ids),nrow=length(unique(students))))

for(i in 1:length(students)){
  for(j in 1:length(ids)){
    attempts<-which(scores$question_id==ids[j] &
                        scores$name==students[i])
    if(length(attempts)==0){finaldat[i,j]<-NA}
    else{
    last.score<-as.numeric(scores$correct[attempts[which(attempts==length(attempts))]])
     finaldat[i,j]<-99
      if(length(last.score)==0){finaldat[i,j]<-NA}
      else{if(last.score==0 | last.score==1){
        finaldat[i,j]<-last.score
      }
      }
    }
  }
}        

finaldat
```

Besides running really slow, it doesn't work because I can't wrap my head around the last.score line. I'm sure there is a tidy verse solution, but I'm stumped. Any tips would be much appreciated.

So output data would be:

```
cbind(c(0,1,1),c(99,99,NA),c(1,99,1))
```

We can see question 6 has been excluded, and any non-binary have been converted to 99's, missing values are NAs, and only final attempts have been kept.

Comment: `object 'fickle' not found`

Comment: Could you please make sure that the input data is correct?  I really find it hard to comprehend and in the end what you're trying is to `pivot_wider` the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a version using `dplyr` and `tidyr`.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

scores <- data.frame(name        = c(1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3),
                     question_id = c(5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8),
                     correct     = c(0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, .5 , "fickle", 1, 2.2, 1),
                     attempt     = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
                     stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

result <- scores %>%
  group_by(name, question_id) %>% 
  filter(attempt == max(as.numeric(as.character(attempt)))) %>% 
  mutate(correct = if(correct != "1" && correct != "0") "99" else correct) %>%
  select(name, question_id, correct) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = question_id, values_from = correct)

result
#> # A tibble: 3 x 5
#>    name `5`   `6`   `7`   `8`  
#>   <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#> 1     1 0     1     99    1    
#> 2     2 1     0     99    99   
#> 3     3 1     1     <NA>  1
```

Comment: I found the `forcats` function `fct_other(correct, keep = c("0", "1"), other_level = "99" )` super flexible. Afterwards an `as.integer(as.character(correct))`

Answer (score 0):

Just to add another solution, I was already working on

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
library(forcats)

dt.scores <- data.table(scores)

dt.scores[, correct := as.integer(as.character(fct_other(correct, keep = c("0", "1"), other_level = "99"))) ]
dt.scores[, attempt := as.integer(as.character(attempt)) ]

dt.scores[,.(name, question_id, correct)] %>% pivot_wider(data = . , names_from = question_id, values_from = correct, values_fn = list(correct = max))
```

Comment: You could also just use data.table (with melt and dcast): `swapCorr <- function(x) {x <- factor(as.character(x)); levels(x) <- ifelse(levels(x)=="1", 1, ifelse(levels(x)=="0", "0", "99")); x}; setDT(scores, key = c("name", "attempt", "correct", "question_id")); scores <- scores[, tail(.SD, 1), c("name", "question_id")]; scores[, correct := swapCorr(correct)]; dcast(melt(scores[,-"attempt"], id.vars=c("name", "question_id")), name ~question_id, value.var="value")`